# EE Rewards Points - How to modify number of points given on a product level?

Tags: magento-enterprise, enterprise-1.13, enterprise-1.14, reward-points

I am trying to develop a way to use Enterprise Editions rewards points in a more useful fashion.

For example say we have a product with manufacturer of "Sony" and a price of $100

The normal reward exchange rate is 1 point for every dollar spent.

I want to be able to have a custom exchange rate depending on what product is added. So for example if manufacturer is "Sony" , on add to cart they get 3 points for each dollar. So normally they would have 100 points but in this new way, they would get 300 points.

Any advice? Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Did you end up finding a way how to do this?

Answer (score -3):

You can add a Shopping Cart price rule where you define the conditions that you need to select the product you want to add extra rewardpoints for (based on the manufacturer attribute, sku or other custom attribute).

In the action section you can define how many extra points you want to add (thru the 'Add Reward Points' field):

[image]

The 'Add Reward Points' is a fixed amount of points given for that promotion, so if you want to add points based on the product price this will not work. You can add multiple rules and give extra points based on the price-step (0-50, 50-100.....).

Comment: Someone please downvote this answer. I appreciate your help but I am well aware of adding a SET amount of points (what the rule does) but there is no way to change the points MULTIPLIER. I have tried reviewing the module but I havent been able to see where the rate is set so then we could make a custom module to override the rate when certain conditions are triggered